# OpenLayers with Google Maps layers on high resolution mobile display

Tags: google-maps, mobile, openlayers, resolution

I am developing a mobile OpenLayers web site which uses the Google Maps Street layer. My problem is that it is almost impossible to read annotations on current generation high resolution displays.

The static Google Maps API (v2) featured a scale option to allow for high resolution screens. Is there anything to scale up the display Google Maps within OpenLayers?

I target specifically the Chrome browser on Android devices.

Cheers,
Dennis

Comment: can you explain please what you mean by annotations? do you mean info popups for markers or something?

Comment: I mean map annotations, like road names. This is my first mobile app and I forgot to use a viewport which resolved this issue.

Comment: cool.. please answer your own question so others can see it if they run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being fairly new to mobile web development I forgot to set a width as a meta tag in the site head. Defining a width fixes the styling problem on high resolution devices.

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=500px" />
</head>
```